# Which part of the code executes inner function?

Tags: javascript, iife

I came across this question in one of the online quizes. The solution I came up with was *function*. BUT, the console logs *number*.

```
var f = (
   function f(){return "1";},
   function g (){return 2;}
)();
console.log(typeof f);
```

My thinking was: `var f` becomes an IIFE, so `typeof f` should be a function.

Now, apparently, `function g()` inside `var f` executes and returns its value to `var f`, so the console logs *number* (or 2, if I just log `f`).

Questions:

1.What is the explanation for *function **comma** anotherFunction*. This is not an object, and also not a variable declaration (like var x, y;)?

2.Somehow the second function is the one that is being returned, but what part of the code is actually executing it?

(I thought that `()` just before the `console.log` call is executing the outer `f` function (which should just define inner functions `f()` and `g()`, but not execute any of them ). The second one gets executed, so , obviously, I was wrong.

Comment: you should remove the space after the `g`

Comment: There is no "outer function".

Comment: Who in their right mind would even write such a thing...

Comment: @andrea-f Why ?

Comment: maybe you have a look to the [comma operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comma_Operator).

Comment: @NinaScholz That does not fully answer the question. Please read it in full. - *"Somehow the second function is the one that is being returned, but what part of the code is actually executing it?"*

Comment: There are some answers about the comma operand, but the main question here is the other part - execution of the inner function

Comment: @Yozex I will write up an answer and link you to it, if this doesn't get reopened

Comment: There is no "outer" and "inner". There are two functions (operands of the comma operator), and the comma operator returns one of them.

Comment: @Yozex [Here's an explanation for now](https://repl.it/@ugam44/KhakiUpsetMatch)

Comment: @Yozex The comma makes it so only the last function is returned. The `()` at the end of `var f = (..)()` is what executes the function `g`. That makes `f`  the value of `2` and is a number.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8228281/what-is-the-function-construct-in-javascript

Comment: Thank you for your effort, I think I got it!